# How to make global variable (or function) in nix file?

Tags: nix, nixos

I want to declare variable `dotfiles_dir` so all other files can see and use it.

For example (not working)

In `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` (it's root file, right?)

```
dotfiles_dir="/home/bjorn/.config/dotfiles";

import "${dotfiles_dir}/nixos/root/default.nix"
```

and use it also in `~/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix` (with https://github.com/rycee/home-manager)

```
import "${dotfiles_dir}/nixos/home/default.nix"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to declare variable dotfiles_dir so all other files can see and use it.

Sorry, but that's not possible. In Nix, there's no such thing as global variables. If there were, it would ruin it's ability to provide reproducible builds because then Nix expressions would have access to undeclared inputs.

`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` is not place store global information, it's technically a NixOS module. But more importantly, it's a function.

However... there's a way to define a value in one place and use it where ever you need it. Something like this:

**/etc/nixos/dotfiles-dir.nix**

```
"/home/bjorn/.config/dotfiles"
```

**~/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix**

```
let 
  dotfiles_dir = import /etc/nixos/dotfiles-dir.nix;
  dotfiles = import (builtins.toPath "${dotfiles_dir}/nixos/home/default.nix");
in 
...
```

You could also get more fancy...

**/etc/nixos/my-settings.nix**

```
{ dotfiles_dir = "/home/bjorn/.config/dotfiles";
, some_other_value = "whatever";
}
```

**~/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix**

```
let 
  dotfiles_dir = (import /etc/nixos/my-settings.nix).dirfiles_dir;
  dotfiles = import (builtins.toPath "${dotfiles_dir}/nixos/home/default.nix");
in 
...
```

Comment: this way I have to carry everywhere path to my settings. Maybe its possible to make it imported in the header (like `{ pkgs, mysettings, ... }:`)?

Comment: That's the syntax for a function, not an import. You can add mysettings as an argument to a function, but the caller of the function will need to provide a value for it. This is the way it works for packages too, it's just made somewhat magical by the top-level expression. There's no way to say "make this value available everywhere" in Nix.